# Print out different messages dependent on gender of patient

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to print out diffrent messages whichever gender the patient has. So i defined an text with an variable:

```
p10 = "Bitte Kodierung überprüfen: Kode gilt überwiegend nur für #{@gender} Patienten."
```

And my code i wrote like this:

```
if patient.geschlecht == '2' && code.geschlecht == 'm' && code.geschlecht_fehler == 'm'
    @gender = 'männliche'
    @arr << p10
  end
if patient.geschlecht == '1' && code.geschlecht == 'w' && code.geschlecht_fehler == 'k'
    @gender = 'weibliche'
    @arr << p10
end
```

But somehow this wont work, in my view i get the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `gender' for #<DiagnoseController:0x50197e0>
```

So what did i wrong? Or how would you print out the different messages?

UPDATE_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_***UPDATE****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**

Now i have no error, but somehow the @gender gets not insertet in the p10 string! Whats wrong?

Comment: Add the full stack trace and the whole controller action code please, I suspect the error is not originating in the part you posted

Comment: can you post your view?

Comment: I updatet my question

Comment: Did I answer you? or you are still facing difficulty, or if I wasn't clear please let me know.

Comment: as i said u are using it first and declaring it later at that time it did not had that value

Comment: DO you have antoher idea, to write it shorter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have defined `p10` first at that time `@gender` din used to exist. so what you can do it either put that `p10` declaration in both the if's after you have defined the gender. or just add diff lines in the `arr` in the if's only, like this.

```
flag = false
if patient.geschlecht == '2' && code.geschlecht == 'm' && code.geschlecht_fehler == 'm'
  @gender = 'männliche'
  flag = true
end
if patient.geschlecht == '1' && code.geschlecht == 'w' && code.geschlecht_fehler == 'k'
  @gender = 'weibliche'
  flag = true
end
@arr << "Bitte Kodierung überprüfen: Kode gilt überwiegend nur für #{@gender} Patienten." if flag
```

In all you can not use the `@gender` before assigning it a value.

Comment: The problem is that i dont want to repeat always the p10! Is there nothing shorter

Comment: Im beginner in programming can you explain me what the flag= flase/true means? But im really super happy with that answer! Thank you!

Comment: what i did was flag is just a variable and i initialized it with false and put true it enters any of the if's so after if if the value of flag is true we can add the statement in the @arr.

Comment: Oh now im facing another problem! What is if both ig statements are true? It will only print out one statement!

Comment: both can never be true your `patient.geschlecht` will either br 1 or 2